# Error deleting elements from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to do a method where I have to delete a number from a vector of integers, and that number is passed as a parameter. The problem that I'm having right now is that when I try to delete the same number in consecutive positions, only one of them is deleted.

For example:

vector = (1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5) and I want to remove the number "2", the result will be:

vector = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

But if the number is not in consecutive positions, the method works fine:

vector = (1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5) ---> remove "2"

vector = (1, 3, 4, 5)

The code that I have is this:

```
void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int> &numbers)
{
    bool hasEntered = false;

    int counter = 0;
    vector<int> deletedNumbers;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] != n)
        {
            counter++;
        }

        else
        {
            counter = 0;
            int counter2 = 0;
            bool deleted = false;

            for(unsigned j = 0; j < deletedNumbers.size() && deleted == false; j++) // Check if a number has been deleted before
            {
                if(deletedNumbers[j] != n)
                {
                    counter2++;
                }

                else
                {
                    deleted = true;
                    counter2 = 0;
                }
            }

            if(counter2 == (int) deletedNumbers.size()) // Remove the number if it hasn't been removed
            {
                deletedNumbers.push_back(n);
                for(unsigned k = 0; k<numbers.size(); k++)
                {
                    if(numbers[k]  == n)
                        numbers.erase(numbers.begin()+k);
                }

                counter2 = 0;
                hasEntered = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the error could be in the condition of the last for, where I finally remove the number.

The counters are used in order to determine if an element has been found or not. And also the method has to check if the item has been removed before.

If you don't understand something, please ask me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just a note. `vector` is not a container suited for deleting elements inside of it. You would be much better using a container suited for the operations you need to use. Like `deque`, or `list`. There is a really good reason why `std::vector` has no method `erase` by standard.

Comment: @luk32 - [std::vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

Comment: Why the hell everyone erases all copies of the element when it's clearly against the example: `vector = (1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)` -> `vector = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: @tloveless And that page states that this is highly inefficient. Even though the erase/remove idiom can overcome this and is certainly what OP needs.

Comment: @tloveless Ok I retract my comment about it not existing. Still, I don't find it smart =)

Comment: @luk32 - I never said it was smart, just pointing out it exists ;) - @pmr - with such a small collection, any inefficiencies are negligible; however, with larger collections, a linked `list` would def. be the better option for efficiency.

Comment: @user3577336 - Your requirements are still somewhat confusing.  Is it that you just want to erase all numbers from the vector that are equal to a certain number, regardless of where the number is located in the vector?  If so, then the `vector::erase/remove` idiom can be used, as shown with my answer.  If your requirements are different, can you state them up front, as your question starts off sounding as if all you want to do is erase a certain number from a vector.

Comment: @tloveless Oh, sorry. I really do appreciate pointing this out to me.

Comment: @luk32 I think that example is an example of wrong behaviour and he wants `(1,3,4,5)` output in both cases  (it is very badly worded)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I rethought it, and I do agree that it is very confusing, and I am not sure what behaviour is expected. I `+1`ed most comprehensive answer (even though it's not best c++) and move forward. I've learned a thing so I am content =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int> &numbers)
{
    vector<int>numbers_without_n;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        if(numbers[i] != n)
            numbers_without_n.push_back(numbers[i]);

    numbers = numbers_without_n;
}
```

Comment: Lol I that way of doing it's great. Much easier, faster and effective. Thank you! :)

Comment: Your last line might be faster by doing `numbers.swap(numbers_without_n)` instead. This will quickly swap the vectors' guts instead of doing a piecewise assignment between them.

Comment: @Blastfurnace you are right, there is a lot of ways to do it, I just tried to show the simplest one.

Comment: FYI this solution creates an unnecessary temporary variable (numbers_without_n), wasting memory temporarily. See the code in my solution, which is more memory-efficient (and still fast).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like too complicated, thus it can contain many bugs.

This would delete all instances of n; O(numbers.size()):

```
void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int> &numbers) {
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); ++j) {
    if (numbers[j] != n) numbers[i++] = numbers[j];
  }
  numbers.resize(i);
}
```

This would delete the first instance of n in each run; O(numbers.size()):

```
void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int> &numbers) {
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size();) {
    if (numbers[j] == n) {
      for (++j; j < numbers.size() && numbers[j] == n; ++j) {
        numbers[i++] = numbers[j];
      }
    } else {
      numbers[i++] = numbers[j++];
    }
  }
  numbers.resize(i);
}
```

This would delete the first instance of n; O(numbers.size()):

```
void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int> &numbers) {
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); ++j) {
    if (numbers[j] == n) {
      for (++j; j < numbers.size(); ++j) {
        numbers[i++] = numbers[j];
      }
      break;
    }
    numbers[i++] = numbers[j];
  }
  numbers.resize(i);
}
```

Pick whichever you need.

Please note that other answers, such as luk32's answer contain simpler code (using more STL) for deleting the first instance of n.

If you want to find and fix the bug in your code, I recommend that you try to find a very short input vector for which it fails, and then single-step through it in a debugger.

Comment: I don't think that gives the same behavior. Looks like the expected output only removes duplicates?

Comment: This removes all copies. It's kind of against the current requirement. @HunterGuy2 I think it should remove the 1st (or last) element, not only dupes. The 2nd example removes the last existing element.

Comment: Then maybe I don't understand the requirements. Could you please give an input for which my code is wrong, and also give the correct output?

Comment: `vector = (1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)` -> `vector = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` ?? Also "Your code looks like too complicated, thus it can contain many bugs." is a big jump. Somewhat justified, but still... It is not a proper logical statement IMO. =)

Comment: @pts I think it works, but IMO mine version is simpler. `O(n)` for deletion is not fast TBH =).

Comment: Based on re-reading the code comments, it looks like it's just supposed to delete the first instance of the number and return.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a loop inside the loop. The easiest way to handle the delete is to delete one item at a time and realize that this will mean you don't want to increment `i` when you have deleted an item. The easiest way to cancel the increment of `i` in the for loop is to decrement it first using `--i`. So you loop becomes

- Check if the item matches the number
- If so, delete the item and decrement i

Answer (score 0):

Use std::remove and vector::erase

```
#include <algorithm>

void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int>& numbers)
{
   numbers.erase(std::remove(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), n), numbers.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since apparently [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) does exists I would use standard `c++` features:

```
void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int> &numbers) {
 auto it = find(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), n);
 if(it != numbers.end()) numbers.erase(it);
}
```

EDIT: Forgot that `end()` is not a valid argument for `erase`.

Comment: think you're missing the parameter to erase()

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure what counter and counter2 are used for - if they're just being used to determine if you've iterated to the end of the vector without finding an element, you don't need them.

For the purpose of 'check if a number has been deleted', you just need a single boolean variable at the very top of the method, i.e. not inside the scope of the for loop.

I believe the following:

```
if(counter2 == (int) deletedNumbers.size()) // Remove the numbers if it hasn't been removed
```

can be replaced with if (!deleted).

So, here's a 'fixed' version while trying to stay as close to your existing logic as possible based on your code comments. This may not be the most efficient/elegant implementation however, I believe I have seen some other answers that use algorithms from the STL library to achieve the same thing.

```
void deleteNumber(int n, vector<int> &numbers)
{
    bool deleted = false;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == n)  // If we've found an instance of the number we're trying to delete
        {
            if (!deleted)  // Check if an instance has already been deleted
            {
                numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + i);  // Remove the number
                deleted = true;  // Flag that we have deleted an instance of the number
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, instead of using a flag for 'deleted' to prevent deleting numbers after the first instance, you could optimize by just returning after you delete the first instance - that will prevent the rest of the loop from executing.